# How to avoid duplicate form submission?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a form and I want to avoid a wrong submission of the form by the user.
How can I do to get avoided with javascript?
Sorry for the spelling mistakes, I must use a translator
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jquery validation plugin` for invalid form submission

you can more detail and tutorial here : [jquery validation plugin tutorial](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a shot in the dark due to the lack of details, but, if you're submiting a form using a button type submit and you want to control when to submit it, pass the click event to the form, and then, in the function, just write

```
event.preventDefault()
```

before all the code... this way the form won't be submitted automatically

Answer (score -1):

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>evitar envio duplicado</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submit() {
                document.getElementById("submit").value = "enviando...";
               document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                return true;
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="formulario" action="#"> <!-- el asterisco le sustituimos por la URL a mandar formulario*/-->

            <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='enviando ...'" /> <!--añadiendo this.form.submit enviamos el formulario-->
        </form>


    </body>

    </html>
```